# How do I expose the javascript in a webpack plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bower, webpack

I have a bower component I am loading via webpack.  I want to expose the javascript in that bower component on every page of an app so I can interact with it?  What is the right way to expose the js?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `require` on all the pages. If you want the browser to download it only once you may need to look in to using the [CommonsChunkPlugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin).